# Setting up a cross browser compatible div structure with the following layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get this right for the last couple of hours, and was unsuccessful, i am not a front-end developer and would appreciate it much if someone could guide me in the right direction. (this is for a hobby project of mine) and i am trying to achieve a cross browser compatible (IE10+/Chrome/FF) div layout (as depicted below)

so far my miserable attempt at trying to get it to work is here -> 
http://jsfiddle.net/0oax4zxx/2/

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
      display:inline-block;
    height:600px;
    width:50px
}
.top {
    display:inlne;
    height:100px;
}
.dynamic {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
.inner-container{
    display:inline-block;

}

<div class="border container">
    <div class="border left">left</div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="border top">top</div>
        <div class="border dynamic"><p>Other html content goes here...</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!
[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a fixed layout. We can do that with position:absolute and use of regular top/left, and widths that use `calc(100% - ...px)`. Like so: http://jsbin.com/zihaniqexayi/1/

Comment: Thanks Mike, Is calc supported on all modern browsers?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "modern". [ie9 + for calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: I'd imagine modern means "if you're on a windows that supports IE9, you're on IE11 due to windows updates, and there is literally no reason for you not to be" (ignoring intranet browsers because their requirements are irrelevant when talking about modern browsers)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to the scroll bar to be on the dynamic area only, you can use absolute positioning for this layout.. Your example is updated at http://jsfiddle.net/0oax4zxx/3/

The code below explains the process

```
html, body {height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}

.border
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
/* setting the top and bottom will put make the element the same height as parent */
.left
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100px; /* fixed width */
    background:#cccccc;
}
/* setting the left and right will put make the element the same width as parent */
.top
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:100px;
    height:100px; /* fixed height */
    background:#ff0000;    
}
.dynamic
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px; /* same as the fixed height */
    left:100px; /* same as the fixed width */
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow:auto; /* making content scroll if too long */
    background:#0000ff;
}
```